# Artillery: How exactly does rampto work in artillery?

Tags: artillery

Not able to understand how rampto works in artillery

```
> - duration: 10
>       arrivalRate: 5
>       rampTo: 10
```

Below is my whole scenario:

```
 - duration: 5
      arrivalRate: 1
    - duration: 10
      arrivalRate: 5
      rampTo: 10
    - duration: 20
      arrivalRate: 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This looks helpful](https://artillery.io/docs/guides/guides/test-script-reference.html#A-ramp-up-followed-by-an-constant-arrival-rate). The gist seems to be that `rampTo` "ramps up" your arrivals gradually, rather than running the full arrival rate straight away. So your example:

```
- duration: 10
  arrivalRate: 5
  rampTo: 10
```

Would expand to:

```
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 0
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 0.5
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 1
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 1.5
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 2
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 2.5
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 3
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 3.5
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 4
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 4.5
- duration: 0.9
  arrivalRate: 5
```

By the end of the original duration of `10`, you would be testing with the full arrival rate of 5. You should probably have a second duration set with a sustained test at this arrival rate.